# Qt Creator can't find any valid Qt versions

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to use Qt Creator, but it is not working. My *hello world* application gets the following error:

> **No valid qt versions found.**
>   Please add a qt version in Tools/Options or via the maintenance tool of the SDK.

In Tools → Options → Tool Chains, I see the auto-detected compilers:

> MinGW runtime (provided with Qt creator)
>   Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 9.0(x86)
>   Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 9.0(amd64)

Googling, I see that it's a bug of Qt Creator but I can't find a fix.

How do I get Qt Creator to work?

Comment: have you downloaded the full Qt SDK or only qtcreator?

Comment: Go to the source -- ask [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/forum.php) or [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/forumdisplay.php?219-Qt).

Comment: QtCreator doesn't come with the SDK, you need to download it, compile and install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Qt Creator 2.4.0

If you find a valid Qt installation under Tools > Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions. If you have no valid Qt installations here you might need to rebuild from source or download the procompiled libraries from qt.nokia.com and add them manually.

When you have a valid Qt installation showing up there which one to build against by opening the Projects tab on the left sidebar. Under Build Settings > General you can select the Qt version AND which toolchain to use for various builds.

Comment: though your answer is accepted, the link doesn't work with me

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried this, Tools->Options->Qt4 shows which qmakes Creator knows about.  If you don't see anything, that's probably your problem.  You can add one manually by clicking Add and finding your qmake.exe.